# Не могу понять почему через некоторое время не работает контекстное меню

Tags: c#, winforms

Написал приложение, которое мониторит папку, если файл есть, то копирует его в другую папку, но с нужным именем. Это в кратце. К примеру работает все часа 4-5 нормально. Через длительное время, когда в папку мониторинга уже давно ничего не попадает - появляется проблема. В трее есть иконка и когда я вызываю контекстное меню из трея. Так вот меню появляется, но как бы зависшее, ни один пункт меню, не выделяется. Я копирую файл в папку мониторинга и он нормально копируется в папку назначения - приложение само не висит, процессор не перегружен. Подскажите, в каком направлении и чем "копать"? Как найти причину подвисания контекстного меню? Спасибо

Comment: UI поток завис, например

Comment: Это происходит не сразу, а всегда через длительное время - савлю на ночь на виртуалке для теста и на утро - висяк.

Comment: что никак не противоречит тому, что у вас зависает UI поток

Comment: @ tym32167. Двойной щелчок мыши по иконке в трее открывает форму для настроек, настройки я сохраняю. Допустим, устанавливаю "Автозапуск приложения". При вызове меню отображается, что данная опция выделена... Но проблема, что меню висит.

Comment: ну а меню запускается в UI потоке, раз меню висит, то и поток висит

Comment: не пойму, если висит, то почему в меню отображаются мои настройки и почему могу вызвать форму для настроек.

Comment: это я не могу знать, вы ж ничего не показали, ни кода, ничего

Comment: хотя я могу быть неправ, это же трей-меню, оно может отработать и не в UI потоке. А другие проги в трее не тупят? Я видел, например, такое, что когда будится комп, он начинает шуршать жестким диском, диск вылетает в 100% занятости и UI всей системы начинает подтупливать

Comment: Если что-то перестаёт работать через длительное время, то виноват может быть сборщик мусора. Вероятно, какие-то ресурсы у вас являются локальными переменными и GC их удалил. Нужно вынести объявления этих ресурсов куда-то выше - сделать полями формы и т. п.

Comment: так... сейчас буду смотреть, хоть в каком-т онаправлении сдвиг.

Comment: Поведение очень смахивает на утечку gdi объектов.

Comment: Кстати, да, может быть утечка gdi-объектов (хендлов). Значит нужно диспозить все `IDisposable` объекты: либо вызывать метод `Dispose`, либо использовать конструкцию `using`.